# Add link to Spring Data REST Repository resource

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I want to create a Link to a resource within a Spring Data REST Repository. I know that we can use `ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo` method to create links to MVC controllers. As far is I understand Spring Data REST creates MVC controllers out of our Repository interfaces. But if I use

```
Instance createdInstance = instanceRepository.save(instance);
Link link = linkTo(InstanceRepository.class).slash(createdInstance.getId()).withSelfRel();
```

to create the link, I just get `http://localhost:8080/2` (without the Repository path). Nothing changes if I specify the path explicitly with the `@RepositoryRestResource` at the Repository.

Of course I could just create the link explicitly, but I don't want to repeat myself.

```
public interface InstanceRepository extends CrudRepository<Instance, Long> {
}
```

Any advice on what I could do to resolve this issue without having to violate DRY principles?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Searching through the Spring Data REST source code I found the class [RepositoryEntityLinks](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/support/RepositoryEntityLinks.java), which is used within the framework. It has a pretty nasty constructor, but (at least in my project) I am able to `@Autowire` the class.

In short the following code does the trick. Nevertheless I would be pleased to hear another persons more educated opinion on this!

```
Link link = entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(InstanceRepository.class, 1L);
```

Comment: Nothing to add, except that the upcoming version 2.4.0 will mention that in the reference documentation explicitly (see [DATAREST-623](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-623) for details).

Comment: I am unable to `@Autowire` `RepositoryEntityLinks` inside of my `ResourceAssemblerSupport` class.  Are you `@Autowiring` in a `@RestController`?

Comment: And for relation OneToMany, when i want to have all link for nested object ?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is confused on how to piece it all together, you need to inject `RepsitoryEntityLinks` into your controller like so. Note no `AutoWired` is needed since spring will automatically inject the values if theres just the 1 constructor.

`entityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(TodoRepository.class)` is saying to spring - "give me the link to the TodoRepositories collection endpoint which would be something like `localhost:8080/api/todos`"

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/api")
    public class PriorityController {

        private RepositoryEntityLinks entityLinks;

        public PriorityController(RepositoryEntityLinks entityLinks) {
            this.entityLinks = entityLinks;
        }

        @GetMapping(value = "/priorities", produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<Resources<Priority>> getPriorities() {
           Link link = entityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(TodoRepository.class);
           resources.add(link);
           return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
        }
    }
```